# Transform MGLAnnotationView Subview

Tags: ios, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to apply a transform in order to rotate a view that I've added as a `MGLAnnotationView`'s subview. It worked well for `MKAnnotationView` but it doesn't for the new annotation view class.

What should the correct approach be for this?

Answer (score 2):

[This particular issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/pull/5287) will be fixed as of the next beta of the Mapbox iOS SDK. (You’ll need to operate on the view’s existing transform rather than starting from the identity transform.) While you’re waiting for the fix, you can create a sublayer (or subview) and apply the transform to the sublayer.